Auth User not fetched Laravel
I have the following function in which I process the paytab payment page:
public function index(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $model = $this->findInvoiceModel($id);

    // card details 
    $cardDetails = getCardDetails($id);
    // Check for event subscription
    $event_subscription = EventSubscription::where('id', function ($query) use ($id) {
      $query->select('module_id')
        ->from('module_invoice')
        ->where(['invoice_id' => $id, 'module_type' => 'event-member-register'])
        ->first();
    })->first();

    if ($model->payment_status != 0) {
      return redirect('/account/profile')->with('success', __('Payment has already been paid'));
    }

    if ($event_subscription) {
      if ($event_subscription->EventData->registration_end < now() || $event_subscription->status == 'cancelled') {
        $message = "Event registration is now closed";
        return view($this->folderName . '.failure', compact('message'));
      }
    }
    // dd($paymentInfo);
    return view($this->folderName . '.index', compact('model', 'request', 'cardDetails'));
  }

The following is the helper function getCardDetails from which the card details are fetched:
function getCardDetails($id)
  {
    $model = Invoices::where('id', $id)->first();

    // Check if the invoice exists
    if (!$model) {
      return [
        'card_method' => '',
        'card_type' => '',
        'card_scheme' => '',
        'card_description' => '',
        'expiry_month' => '',
        'expiry_year' => ''
      ];
    }

    $payment_ref = DB::table('payments')->where('user_id', $model->user_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();

    // If payment reference or transaction ID is not found, return empty card details
    if (!$payment_ref || !$payment_ref->transaction_id) {
      return [
        'card_method' => '',
        'card_type' => '',
        'card_scheme' => '',
        'card_description' => '',
        'expiry_month' => '',
        'expiry_year' => ''
      ];
    }

    $profile_id = "profile id"; // Set your profile ID dynamically
    $tran_ref = $payment_ref->transaction_id;
    $authorization_key = "authorication key"; // Set your authorization key dynamically

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://secure.paytabs.com/payment/query',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        "profile_id" => $profile_id,
        "tran_ref" => $tran_ref
      )),
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: ' . $authorization_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Decode the response
    $data = json_decode($response, true);

    // Extract only the card-related details
    $cardDetails = [
      'card_method' => $data['payment_info']['payment_method'] ?? '',
      'card_type' => $data['payment_info']['card_type'] ?? '',
      'card_scheme' => $data['payment_info']['card_scheme'] ?? '',
      'card_description' => $data['payment_info']['payment_description'] ?? '',
      'expiry_month' => $data['payment_info']['expiryMonth'] ?? '',
      'expiry_year' => $data['payment_info']['expiryYear'] ?? '',
    ];

    return $cardDetails;
  }

Now the issue is that the user should be logged-in in order to have the existing card details shown on the payment card page else add new card form should be shown. But if anyone gets the link of paytab like
testdomain.com/pay-tabs/20938
the payment card details are shown. How to fix it?
The Auth::check or Auth::user() is not working at all.

Add middleware auth to your web route for this functions. You can add construct function to related class too.

The issue was fixed. But passing web guard
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {     your route });

In your Route file, you will need to add an auth service to check if the user is logged in or not. I've used Sentinel in the past, you can read up on them here: cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/8.x
Once you setup the check on the route, it might look something like this:
Route::get('/admin/food-type/create', ['middleware' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminController@createFoodType']);

You can see that I've passed in the middleware to the route, and so if the route is hit without the user being logged in, they will get a message like "You are not logged in! Please signup or login to continue." You can route them to a login page, or however you want to handle it at that point.

The issue was fixed. But passing web guard Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {     your route });
